# Pagination logic for html page[Android Ebpub Reader]

Tags: javascript, android, html, pagination

I have been developing Android epub reader application, Using which I can Read Epubs, page by page even if it's font sizes have changed.All  I need to do is to paginate html page, So That I can give a user book-like reading experience.that html page will contain images.

Currently I tried to implement it using Columising html page
using following CSS Style.

```
 sytle="<style type=\"text/css\">body {width:"+displayWidth+"px;    
  height:"+displayHeight+"px;-webkit-column-gap:"+pagegap+"px; 
  -webkit-column-width:"+width+"px; -webkit-column-height:"
   +displayHeight+"px; text-align:justify ;} </style>";
```

But problem with this approach is it show  some images splitted ,which will be in different 
columns.right and bottom of paragraph get clipped It Also have some Performance problem.

Is there is any better way to do pagination or  Atleast How can I solve this splitting of image problem

Any informative links and hints all are welcome.

Thanks for your time.

Regards,
Kariyachan

Comment: where are you getting the data from?

Comment: What else am I trying to do? If you don't answer our questions, how do you think we're going to clear our doubts?

Comment: @Sheikh Aman .Sorry about that. Epub file is in Application's assets folder.And I succeed in Unzipping Epub file which is then stored in cache folder, rendered  corresponding html file in webview .thanks for your time.

Comment: Hey were you able to find answer to this ? Just wondering what approach have you finalized.

Comment: Hi Kariyachan, can u pls explain how did u solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you can query the file, that you wish to take the data from, multiple times, in a way that it returns a particular set of data every time, then you might implement Paging functionality, by querying the file for a new set every time the user turns a page.